# How can extract points which are formed a convex hull of 3 dimensions polygon in Matlab by using convexhull functions?

Tags: matlab, convex-hull, convex-polygon, convex-optimization

I use different convex hull functions in Matlab to find points coordinates which are formed the convex hull. however, these functions return the matrix of triangles.
How can I specify those points?
Thanks.
Sepideh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Maybe if the following doesn't clarify things you can edit your post to include the name of the MATLAB function you are using and a snippet of code?

The `convhull` function in MATLAB *does* return the index of coordinates in the convex hull.

In the following example, `(x(k), y(k))` are the coordinates. (taken straight from [convhull doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/convhull.html))

```
xx = -1:.05:1; yy = abs(sqrt(xx));
[x,y] = pol2cart(xx,yy);
k = convhull(x,y);
plot(x(k),y(k),'r-',x,y,'b+')
```

[image: convhull example]

It's the same thing if you are using `convexhull` instead ([convexhull doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.convexhull.html)).

```
x = rand(10,1);
y = rand(10,1);
dt = DelaunayTri(x,y);
k = convexHull(dt);
plot(x,y, '.', 'markersize',10); 
hold on;
plot(x(k), y(k), 'r'); 
hold off;
```

[image: convexhull example]

Comment: Thanks. However, I need the coordinates of those formed convex. from the shape, it is easy to find out but I have many 3-dimensions points.

Comment: Can I ask you what is inside variable k? maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: (x,y) are all the points (the blue dots). k are the index of those points that form the convex hull. Put it into matlab and you'll find that x(k(1)), y(k(1)) is one point, x(k(2)), y(k(2)) is another point, and so on...